# How to link to html in a folder not directly connected

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website with simple HTML+CSS. How do I create a hyperlink (href) in an HTML file, to an HTML file in a folder, that is not directly related.

See picture. If I want to insert a link in HTML 4 to HTML 3.
I know one can use ..\HTML2.html to go back in parent folder, but what is the best way here?

[image]

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I can't get the clear picture about your requirement. So can I ask you a question?
What do you mean by that - a folder?

Comment: either use absolute path, starting from `/` or relative like `../../` (note: not \ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing **/** points to the relative root directory. So you can just do `<a href="/html3/html3.html">HTML 3</a>` and it should take you to HTML3.

You can also use `<a href="../../html3/html3.html">HTML 3</a>` as you seem to know.

General recommendation would be to pick the closest path. If it's from the root, then select the first. If it's from a relative point from where you are, then the second.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your drawing, I assume that node 1 is the root so the simplest way would be: .\html3.html